# How to fix infinite loop spawning from __str__ method?

Tags: python, loops, oop, recursion

```
File "C:\Users\kevin\Documents\Programs\ParLumen\trait.py", line 76, in __str__
    ret_str = super().__str__()
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Documents\Programs\ParLumen\trait.py", line 39, in __str__
    ret_str += f'{self.name}\n'
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

There are many, many more lines of this, however it's just the same two lines repeating, and then the final, different line is, "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

I'm not really sure why this is occurring.

Here is the code causing the issue:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum, unique

from parlumen.game import *

# Base Trait class
class Trait(ABC):

    def __init__(self, name, short_desc="No Desc", long_desc=None):
        self.name = name
        # self.value = value # may restrict this with req. 'avail_values()' func

        """
        if short_desc is not "No Desc":
            self.short_desc = short_desc
        """
        self.short_desc = short_desc

        if long_desc is None:
            self.long_desc = self.short_desc
        else:
            self.long_desc = long_desc

    @abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        ret_str = ""

        ret_str += f'{self.name}\n'
        ret_str += f'{self.long_desc}'

        return ret_str



# Area of Effect Definition

@unique
class Focus(Enum):
    NoFocus  = 'None'
    Origin   = 'Origin'
    Reversed = 'Reversed'

class AreaOfEffect(Trait):

    def __init__(self, area, focus=None):
        super().__init__(self, "Area of Effect")

        self.area = area

        if focus is None :
            self.focus = Focus.NoFocus
        else:
            self.focus = focus

        self.long_desc = f"Gives an attack or spell an area of effect of self.area"

    def __str__(self):
        ret_str = super().__str__()

        ret_str += f"\nArea of Effect: {self.area}, Focus: {self.focus}"

        return ret_str

aoe = AreaOfEffect(3, Focus.Origin)

print(aoe)
```

More specifically, the issue seems to pertain my `__str__` method for `Trait` seems to not like having `self.name` or `self.long_desc` -- that is when the issue occurs.

This is sort of a mess in general, but I'm really trying to figure this out before continuing on. Strange that it only happens for Trait and not the subclass `AreaOfEffect`'s `__str__`

Comment: Trying to force it to be overridden? Not really necessary / I'm not sure if that'll cause any issues (still not 100% familiar with Python) but I've already ruled that out as the issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in Python, providing default functionality in abstract methods is fine -- and yeah I understand _why_ they're used, generally, I was just using that to force any subclasses to implement the method -- is that not ok?

Comment: Please ignore everything I said, I did not see you code block was scrollable. Time to go sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change:

```
super().__init__(self, "Area of Effect")
```

To:

```
super().__init__("Area of Effect")
```

you are setting `name` to an object instance, which then calls `str` recursively when trying to format `name`.